# Android - colors.xml resource to int value

Tags: android, resources

I have a bunch of colors defined in the colors.xml. I need to get their int representation not their resource id so that I can manipulate the alpha and the colors in my code. How can I do this?

```
mColor = R.color.blue; // gets resource id not the actual color as an int.
mColor &= ~0xFF000000;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29) method of Resources returns the color in 0xAARRGGBB format;

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.white); // color is now 0xFFFFFFFF
int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
int red = Color.red(color);
...
```

Comment: Perfect and the Color. functions will come in handy.

Comment: android.content.res.Resources doesn't have a static method `getColor`. Did you mean `getResources().getColor()`?

Comment: getColor() is deprecated

Comment: How to getColor(resourceId) now that it is depricated?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.some_color);`

This returns the int representation of the color associated with a particular resource ID.